# Не могу вычитать значение нескольких input на странице

Tags: html, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть сайт где я вычитываю значение двух input из нескольких по два. Пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cals_place_2').on('change', function() {
        if ($('.cals_place_1') != '') {
            if ($('.cals_place_2') != '') {
                var value1 = parseInt($('.cals_place_1').val());
                var value2 = parseInt($('.cals_place_2').val());
                var value_sum = value1 + value2;
                alert(value_sum);
            };
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ui-ctl-element cals_place_1" data-calc_id="<?=$item['ID']?>" placeholder="Введите значение">
 <input type="text" class="ui-ctl-element cals_place_1" data-calc_id="<?=$item['ID']?>" placeholder="Введите значение">
 <input type="text" class="ui-ctl-element cals_place_1" data-calc_id="<?=$item['ID']?>" placeholder="Введите значение">
 <input type="text" class="ui-ctl-element cals_place_1" data-calc_id="<?=$item['ID']?>" placeholder="Введите значение">
 <input type="text" class="ui-ctl-element cals_place_1" data-calc_id="<?=$item['ID']?>" placeholder="Введите значение">
 <input type="text" class="ui-ctl-element cals_place_1" data-calc_id="<?=$item['ID']?>" placeholder="Введите значение">
```

Может ли кто либо объяснить, как я смогу исполнить данный код с помощью ID?

Comment: Допустил ошибку, второй элемент input после cals_place_1 называется cals_place_2

Comment: если тебе нужно передать это в значение какого то поля то просто полученный результат присвой через `val`

Comment: Спасибо всем кто соучаствовал. Вы мне помогли